# Filling WPF Datagrid at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, datagrid

I have small project that I was working on using Windows Forms, but now part of the requirements is that it should be done in WPF.

I have 2 rows datagrid the first row should be filled manually at runtime, then some calculations will happen and the values will be automatically filled in the second row

[image]

I want to implement this in WPF any suggestions?

Regards

Comment: I am not not asking for a code, I am asking for tips. Which you could simply provide instead of putting effort in posting this link.

Comment: `I am asking for tips` - forget winforms and all it's archaic ways. It's useless. Learn MVVM Before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. Still, your question is not in an appropiate format for StackOverflow. you need to post the code you already tried. This site is not for "suggestions", it's about specific problems with pieces of code or functionalities.